# Hosting Chainlink Node on AWS, can't access the Admin Portal

Tags: amazon-web-services, chainlink

I've successfully deployed a chainlink node on AWS following this tutorial:

https://aws-quickstart.github.io/quickstart-chainlinklabs-chainlink-node/#_parameter_reference

I'm to the part of 'Post Deployment Steps'. However, I have no idea how to access the admin console for Chainlink. Where would I find my Application Load Balancer Endpoint? I'm sure I'm just missing it, but I cannot find it for the life of me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi @harrisoncolewilkinson

This is an issue in the documentation...
and a chance to improvement!

Could you make an issue on the docs?

Thank you so much.